# How to cast an object to field type in Java?

Tags: java, c#, json, casting

Hello everyone and thank you in advance.
I use Reflection in Java to get all class fields and fill them with values from just deserialized JSON message. But I always get an error like

```
    Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
Can not set short field Message.Error to java.lang.String
```

Here's the fragment where it happens:

```
public static Message Decode(String request) {
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(request);
    Message msg = new Message();
    for (Field fld :msg.getClass().getDeclaredFields())
        if (obj.has(fld.getName())) {
            try {
                msg.getClass().getField(fld.getName()).set(msg, obj.get(fld.getName()));
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                return null;
            } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
                return null;
            }
        }
    return msg;
}
```

Here I don't use any cast yet because I haven't found any useful information about casting to dynamic types. Maybe someone had the same trouble.

P.S.> If someone knows the same solution for C# I'll be thankful for it too. My client is C# based.

Comment: Are you trying to reinvent `Message msg = gson.fromJson(request, Message.class)`?

Comment: may be the problem in                             msg.getClass().getField(fld.getName()).set(msg, obj.get(fld.getName()));  this line, check once this line carefully.

Comment: Please don't remove indentation. It helps to better see scope of method/variables.

Comment: KishoreReddy, no, this line works properly. I've checked.

Comment: Can you post the whole stack trace? In which line is this exception thrown?

Comment: The value in the JSONObject is always a String. You are trying to assign it to a field of type `short`. You need to parse the short first, meaning you need to check each field's type and act accordingly. There are libraries to do these things, why are you doing it yourself?

Comment: Pshemo, what namespace or library uses `gson`?

Comment: Gson is library: https://sites.google.com/site/gson/Home

Comment: RealSkeptic, I'm new to Java and to understand how things work I'm trying to do some tasks myself without using external libs. You say that I need to check each field's type and act accordingly - actually that is that post's question. How exactly to cast.

Comment: You don't cast. You can't cast a `String` to a `short` (or a `Short` which is what you'll need in this case). You need to *parse* the string using a method from the `Short` class. But I think doing this level of reflection is beyond your current level of Java knowledge. You should use a library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to reinvent something like [gson](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/Home) library which allows us to simply

```
Message msg = gson.fromJson(request, Message.class);
```

DEMO:

```
class Message{
    private short length;
    private String text;
    private String whatever;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Message [length=" + length + ", text=" + text + ", whatever=" + whatever
                + "]";
    }       
}

public class Demo {    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String request = "{'length':10, 'text':'foo bar'}";
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Message msg = gson.fromJson(request, Message.class);
        System.out.println(msg);
    }
}
```

Result: `Message [length=10, text=foo bar, whatever=null]`

Comment: Thank you. Works perfectly.